# Jboss Portal Render switch on liferay what?

Tags: jboss, liferay, render

Hello i now this question is very general but i must ask it :) i change Jboss portal on liferay portal and now i have classes like this

```
      myclass1 extends AbstractObjectRenderer implements RegionRenderer //A region renderer is responsible to create the markup container for a set of portlets on a page region. 
***methods
    renderHeader(final RendererContext rendererContext, final RegionRendererContext rrc)
    public final void renderBody(final RendererContext rendererContext, final RegionRendererContext rrc)
    public final void renderFooter(final RendererContext rendererContext, final RegionRendererContext rrc)
***methods


     myclass2 extends AbstractObjectRenderer implements WindowRenderer 
***methods 
         public final void render(final RendererContext rendererContext, final WindowRendererContext wrc)//
***methods   

     myclass3 extends AbstractObjectRenderer implements PortletRenderer 
***methods
            public final void render(final RendererContext rendererContext, final PortletRendererContext prc)//Render the markup of a portlet.
***methods

    and last one 


 myclass4   extends AbstractObjectRenderer implements DecorationRenderer 
***methods
            public final void render(final RendererContext rendererContext, final DecorationRendererContext drc)//Create the markup for the portlet decoration 
***methods
```

This 4 class is used to provide some elements like colors, text, pictures etc. I have everything ready only thing which i need is tool from liferay portal which can do same job. I found AssetRender but it supports only assets from assets asset framework,can't check this couse can't find any tutorial about other use than asset render.As i said i already have everything prepared and i need only something to render.

I know this look bad :) but i looking for tool, class or something which have similar functionality in liferay. I take everything what u have :) 
Short Sample

```
public final void render(final RendererContext rendererContext, final WindowRendererContext wrc)
throws RenderException {
PrintWriter out = rendererContext.getWriter();
out.print("<div class=\"portlet-container\">");
out.print("<table cellspacing=\"1\" border=\"5\" width=\"88%\">");
out.print("<tbody>"); 
...
    out.print("</table>");
    out.print("</div>");
```

Comment: if only you could take some time to format the code and make your question a little more elaborate and not in a hurry. It would make a little sense as to what you are looking for and get some nice answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just found Custom Global Markup 6.1.0.1 it can put some HTML just like jboss Portal add. But maybe someone with expirience can tell me it more about this tool, for example , is it provides some api that i can use  like jboss classes above and where i can find more information, maybe someone knows good source. Thanks in advence.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify more what you are trying to achieve? It seems that you want do define some markup that is displayed on each page, is it correct? In that case you need to use [Liferay themes](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-liferay-them-7). You define wrapping markup and its styling in themes. There are also layouts that define whether the page has 1 column, 2 columns or some more complicated structure.